# Anchor link cutting off header

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with anchor links on my page. When clicked my header element gets partially obscured. The bug relates to the use of:

```
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Which I need to stop an overflow bug (due to my use of CSS rotate, which I need for branding / style).

I've tried removing and replacing the above with popular alternatives like:

```
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

But this causes other issues.

Any and all suggestion appreciated. Full code enclosed. To simulate issue run the code, click full screen (on desktop) then click the 'about us' button.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("primaryNav");
  if (x.className === "bg-blue header-nav") {
    x.className += " open";
  } else {
    x.className = "bg-blue header-nav";
  }
}
```

```css
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:0;
 font:inherit;
 font-size:100%;
 vertical-align:baseline
}
html{
 line-height:1
}
ol,ul{
 list-style:none
}
table{
 border-collapse:collapse;
 border-spacing:0
}
caption,th,td{
 text-align:left;
 font-weight:normal;
 vertical-align:middle
}
q,blockquote{
 quotes:none
}
q:before,q:after,blockquote:before,blockquote:after{
 content:"";
 content:none
}
a img{
 border:none
}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,menu,nav,section,summary{
 display:block
}
@font-face{
 font-family:quicksandbold;
 src:url(../fonts/quicksand-bold-webfont.eot);
 src:url(../fonts/quicksand-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(../fonts/quicksand-bold-webfont.woff) format("woff"),url(../fonts/quicksand-bold-webfont.ttf) format("truetype"),url(../fonts/quicksand-bold-webfont.svg#quicksandbold) format("svg");
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal
}
@font-face{
 font-family:quicksandregular;
 src:url(../fonts/quicksand-regular-webfont.eot);
 src:url(../fonts/quicksand-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(../fonts/quicksand-regular-webfont.woff) format("woff"),url(../fonts/quicksand-regular-webfont.ttf) format("truetype"),url(../fonts/quicksand-regular-webfont.svg#quicksandregular) format("svg");
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal
}
article li,h1,p,span{
 font-family:quicksandregular
}
#blogintro header,.fpblog time,footer p,a,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
 font-family:quicksandbold
}
#primaryNav,.lrg-font,h2{
 font-size:1.4em
}
h1{
 font-size:8vw
}
h1 span.full{
 font-size:11vw
}
.width-fix{
 width:89%
}
.rotate p{
 font-size:1em;
 line-height:1
}
p,.stop-rotate p,.stop-rotate ul li{
 line-height:1.4;
 font-size:1.2em
}
h3,h4{
 font-size:1.4em
}
small{
 font-size:0.8em
}
ul{
 text-align:left;
 margin:0 auto;
 max-width:800px;
 padding-left:30px;
 width:70%
}
ul li{
 padding-bottom:5px
}
ul li::before{
 content:"\2022";
 color:#000;
 display:inline-block;
 width:1em;
 margin-left:-1em
}
body{
 background-color:#27AAE1
}
*{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:0;
 margin:0
}
.hide{
 display:none
}
.full-height{
 display:grid;
 width:100vw;
 height:calc(100vh - 92px)
}
.limit-width p,footer{
 margin:0 auto;
 max-width:90%
}
.limit-width-lrg p{
 margin:0 auto;
 width:65%;
 max-width:870px
}
.white{
 color:#fff
}
.bg-blue{
 background-color:#27AAE1
}
.blue{
 color:#27AAE1
}
.bold,.bold li,.bold p{
 font-family:quicksandbold
}
.cntr{
 text-align:center
}
.bg-white{
 background-color:#fff
}
.rotate{
 transform:rotate(-15deg)
}
.stop-rotate{
 transform:rotate(15deg)
}
.txt-center{
 display:grid;
 align-items:center
}
.txt-base{
 display:grid;
 align-items:end
}
.force-base{
 bottom:0;
 position:absolute;
 left:calc(50% - 200px)
}
.mrg-top{
 margin-top:10%
}
body .mrg-top-sml{
 margin-top:40px
}
.pad-top{
 padding-top:20px
}
.pad-top-lrg{
 padding-top:40px
}
.pad-top-xlrg{
 padding-top:13.75vh
}
.pad-btm{
 padding-bottom:20px
}
.pad-top-sml{
 padding-top:5%
}
.section-pad{
 padding:15% 0
}
.bg-2 .button{
 color:#ECEFF1;
 border-color:#ECEFF1
}
.button--winona{
 overflow:hidden;
 padding:0;
 -webkit-transition:border-color 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
 transition:border-color 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
 transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1)
}
.button--winona::after,.button--winona>span{
 padding:1em 0;
 transition:transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
 transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
 -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1)
}
.button--winona:hover{
 background-color:#fff
}
.button--border-thick{
 border:3px solid
}
.button--text-thick{
 font-weight:600
}
.button--text-upper{
 letter-spacing:2px;
 text-transform:uppercase
}
.button--size-s{
 font-size:14px
}
.button{
 min-width:150px;
 max-width:210px;
 display:block;
 margin:0 auto;
 border:3px #27AAE1;
 border-style:dashed;
 background:rgba(39,170,225,0.12);
 color:inherit;
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
 -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale
}
button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{
 -webkit-appearance:button;
 cursor:pointer
}
button,input{
 line-height:normal
}
button{
 align-items:flex-start;
 text-align:center
}
.button--winona>span{
 display:block
}
.button>span{
 vertical-align:middle
}
.button--winona::after,.button--winona>span{
 padding:1em 0;
 -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
 transition:transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
 transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1)
}
.button--winona:hover::after{
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}
.button--winona::after{
 content:attr(data-text);
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 opacity:0;
 color:#000;
 -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 25%, 0);
 transform:translate3d(0, 25%, 0)
}
.button--winona:hover>span{
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
 transform:translate3d(0, -25%, 0)
}
a.btn-link{
 color:inherit;
 text-decoration:none
}
#primaryNav{
 padding:0 20px;
 position:relative;
 text-align:center
}
#primaryNav a:first-of-type{
 padding-top:20px
}
#primaryNav a{
 display:none;
 color:#fff;
 padding-bottom:20px;
 text-decoration:none
}
#primaryNav a#nav-burger{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 right:20px;
 top:-50px;
 z-index:999
}
#primaryNav.open a{
 display:block
}
#primaryNav #nav-burger{
 width:25px;
 height:23px;
 position:relative;
 -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
 transform:rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
 transition:.5s ease-in-out;
 cursor:pointer
}
#primaryNav #nav-burger span{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 height:3px;
 width:100%;
 background:#fff;
 border-radius:9px;
 opacity:1;
 left:0;
 -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
 transform:rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
 transition:.25s ease-in-out
}
#primaryNav #nav-burger span:nth-child(1){
 top:0px;
 -webkit-transform-origin:left center;
 -moz-transform-origin:left center;
 -o-transform-origin:left center;
 transform-origin:left center
}
#primaryNav #nav-burger span:nth-child(2){
 top:7px;
 -webkit-transform-origin:left center;
 -moz-transform-origin:left center;
 -o-transform-origin:left center;
 transform-origin:left center
}
#primaryNav #nav-burger span:nth-child(3){
 top:14px;
 -webkit-transform-origin:left center;
 -moz-transform-origin:left center;
 -o-transform-origin:left center;
 transform-origin:left center
}
#primaryNav.open #nav-burger span:nth-child(1){
 -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
 transform:rotate(45deg);
 top:0;
 left:5px
}
#primaryNav.open #nav-burger span:nth-child(2){
 width:0%;
 opacity:0
}
#primaryNav.open #nav-burger span:nth-child(3){
 -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
 top:18px;
 left:5px
}
#container{
 overflow:hidden
}
#logo{
 padding-top:20px;
 text-align:center
}
#logo svg{
 max-width:120px
}
.spill{
 width:130%;
 margin-left:-15%
}
.stripe-sml{
 height:11vh
}
.stripe-sml p{
 line-height:1.5;
 padding-bottom:18px
}
.stripe-lrg{
 height:18vh
}
#scroll-down{
 max-width:30px
}
footer{
 text-align:center
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 50px){
 .foo2{
  display:none
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 501px){
 h1{
  font-size:40px
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 801px){
 .limit-width p{
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:60%
}
 .full-height{
  height:calc(100vh - 154px)
}
 .mrg-top{
  margin-top:5%
}
 h1{
  font-size:6vw;
  line-height:1.4
}
 h1 .white.bold{
  line-height:2;
  font-size:0.73em
}
 h1 .full{
  margin-bottom:-2%
}
 h3,h4{
  font-size:2vw
}
 ul{
  width:100%;
  padding-left:80px
}
 .lrg-title{
  font-size:3vw
}
 #primaryNav a{
  display:inline-block !important;
  padding:20px 10px
}
 #primaryNav a#nav-burger{
  display:none !important
}
 .height-override{
  height:auto
}
 .stripe-lrg h1 br{
  display:none
}
 #scroll-down{
  bottom:20px;
  position:absolute;
  left:calc(50% - 30px)
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Lorem ipsum. | Lorem ipsum.Lorem ipsum.</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="#" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link href="/v2/assets/styles/screen.css?236" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
  <header class="bg-blue" id="top">
  <div id="logo" class="float">
    <a href="#">
  <svg id="a3ce43e8-fb65-4daf-adde-8a5b63a92355" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 115.71 66.3"><defs><style>.b619fcf4-8929-47b2-8667-741fdd67a7c1{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>Lorem ipsum.</title><g id="b100e093-4f59-489c-bf94-25ea2e312f6f" data-name="Group 1"><path id="ba36fb6c-3443-4def-ab41-3ef77b8ca3b4" data-name="Path 1" class="b619fcf4-8929-47b2-8667-741fdd67a7c1" d="M90.17,52.58a22,22,0,1,1,19.07-33.09l6.36-3.65a29.57,29.57,0,1,0-.09,29.52l-6.33-3.68A22,22,0,0,1,90.17,52.58Z" transform="translate(0.11 -0.31)"/><path id="e0462462-ad6f-44e0-9063-0ba927c00cc9" data-name="Path 2" class="b619fcf4-8929-47b2-8667-741fdd67a7c1" d="M45.7,5.27a29.5,29.5,0,0,0-16.41-5h0A29.63,29.63,0,0,0,4.53,13.57C.28,20-.24,24.86-.09,34.43V66.61H7.18V49.87A29.7,29.7,0,1,0,45.7,5.27Zm1.93,37c-.25.36-.5.72-.76,1.06l-.24.32c-.19.24-.38.47-.58.7l-.28.33c-.21.23-.41.45-.63.67a3.07,3.07,0,0,1-.25.26c-.3.3-.6.59-.91.87l-.09.08c-.28.25-.57.5-.87.73l-.3.24L42,48l-.34.23c-.25.18-.51.34-.77.5a2.61,2.61,0,0,1-.28.17c-.35.22-.71.42-1.07.61l-.16.08-1,.46-.35.15c-.26.12-.53.23-.8.33l-.37.14c-.3.11-.59.21-.89.3a2.29,2.29,0,0,1-.28.09c-.38.12-.78.23-1.17.33l-.25.06-.95.2-.39.07-.84.12-.4,0q-.48.06-1,.09l-.26,0c-.4,0-.81,0-1.22,0h-.23c-.4,0-.8,0-1.21,0l-.34,0-1.39-.15-.19,0c-.4-.06-.81-.14-1.22-.22l-.35-.08c-.46-.1-.91-.22-1.37-.35l-.14,0c-.41-.12-.82-.26-1.23-.41l-.34-.13c-.45-.18-.9-.36-1.34-.57l-.08,0c-.41-.19-.82-.41-1.23-.63l-.33-.19c-.43-.24-.85-.5-1.27-.78A22,22,0,0,1,10.9,17.79c.24-.36.5-.72.75-1.06l.25-.32c.18-.24.37-.47.57-.7l.29-.33c.2-.23.41-.45.62-.67l.25-.27c.3-.3.6-.59.91-.86l.12-.1c.27-.24.55-.48.84-.71l.32-.25.7-.51.35-.24c.25-.17.5-.34.76-.5l.28-.17c.35-.21.71-.41,1.07-.6l.19-.1c.3-.16.6-.3.92-.44l.36-.17.79-.32.38-.15L22.5,9l.28-.09c.39-.12.78-.22,1.17-.32l.27-.06c.31-.08.62-.14.92-.2l.4-.07.83-.13.41-.05,1-.09L28,8c.4,0,.81,0,1.21,0h.26c.39,0,.79,0,1.18,0L31,8l1.38.15.21,0q.6.09,1.2.21l.35.08c.46.1.91.22,1.36.35l.16.05c.41.12.81.26,1.22.41l.34.13c.45.17.89.36,1.33.56l.08,0c.42.2.82.41,1.23.63l.33.19c.43.24.85.5,1.27.77a22.07,22.07,0,0,1,6.18,30.58Z" transform="translate(0.11 -0.31)"/></g></svg>
 </a>
  </div>
</header>

<nav id="primaryNav" class="bg-blue header-nav">
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">About Us</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="nav-burger" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <span></span>
 <span></span>
 <span></span>
  </a>
</nav>  
  <!-- Home Content -->
<article>
  <section class="bg-blue full-height">
   <section class="rotate bg-white txt-base cntr mrg-top stripe-sml spill">
  <p class="force-base"><span class="bold">We're rebuilding our website...</span><br>Check back shortly to see what we've been up to!</p>
 </section>
   <section class="cntr spill txt-center rotate stripe-lrg height-override">
  <h1>
   <div class="full">Lorem ipsum.</div>
   <br>
   <div class="white bold">Lorem ipsum. Digital Agency</div>
  </h1>
 </section>
   <section class="rotate cntr bg-white txt-center stripe-lrg spill">
  <p>Think web design, think Lorem ipsum.</p>
    <a class="btn-link" href="#about-us">
    <button class="button button--winona button--border-thick button--round-l button--text-upper button--size-s button--text-thick" data-text="Read More"><span>About Us</span></button>
  </a>
    <p>We Rethink, We Build, We Optimise</p>
 </section>
 <section class="cntr stripe-lrg">
     <a href="#about-us"><svg id="scroll-down" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 27.22 26.16"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>Scroll Down</title><g id="Group_2" data-name="Group 2"><path id="Path_3" data-name="Path 3" class="cls-1" d="M12.81,26.14,1.11,14.44a1.91,1.91,0,0,1,2.7-2.7h0L14.16,22.1,24.51,11.75a1.91,1.91,0,0,1,2.7,2.7h0l-11.7,11.7a1.91,1.91,0,0,1-2.69,0Z" transform="translate(-0.55 -0.55)"/></g><g id="Group_4" data-name="Group 4"><path id="Path_3-2" data-name="Path 3-2" class="cls-1" d="M12.81,15.5,1.11,3.8a1.91,1.91,0,0,1,2.7-2.7h0L14.16,11.46,24.51,1.11a1.91,1.91,0,0,1,2.7,2.7h0l-11.7,11.7a1.91,1.91,0,0,1-2.69,0Z" transform="translate(-0.55 -0.55)"/></g></svg></a>
 </section>
  </section>
  <section class="section-pad limit-width">
 <h2 id="about-us" class="white cntr lrg-title pad-btm">About Us</h2>
 <p class="bold white cntr">Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.</p>
  </section>
  <section class="rotate bold bg-white section-pad cntr txt-center pad-btm limit-width-lrg spill">
 <span class="stop-rotate">
    <h3 class="pad-btm">Work With Us</h3>
 <p class="bold pad-btm">Lorem ipsum.</p>
 <p class="pad-btm">Lorem ipsum.</p> 
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <h4 class="pad-btm pad-top-lrg mrg-top-sml">What we're looking for:</h4>
 <ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
 </ul>
 <a class="btn-link" href="#">
   <button class="mrg-top-sml button button--winona button--border-thick button--round-l button--text-upper button--size-s button--text-thick" data-text="Apply Now"><span>Apply Now</span></button>
 </a>
 </span>
  </section>
</article>
  <footer class="pad-top-xlrg">
  <p class="pad-top white"><small>Lorem Ipsum is a trading style of 'Lorem Ipsum'.</small></p>
  <p class="white pad-btm"><small>&copy; Lorem Ipsum Copyright 2020, All Rights Reserved.</small></p>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixes:**

> I just remove `overflow` form `#container`as the issue is with this overflow, and add
>   `overflow-x:hidden`to `body` and also add `scroll-behavior: smooth` to
>   `html` and `body` for smooth scrolling.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("primaryNav");
  if (x.className === "bg-blue header-nav") {
    x.className += " open";
  } else {
    x.className = "bg-blue header-nav";
  }
}
```

```css
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:0;
 font:inherit;
 font-size:100%;
 vertical-align:baseline
}
html{
 line-height:1
}

ol,ul{
 list-style:none
}
table{
 border-collapse:collapse;
 border-spacing:0
}
caption,th,td{
 text-align:left;
 font-weight:normal;
 vertical-align:middle
}
q,blockquote{
 quotes:none
}
q:before,q:after,blockquote:before,blockquote:after{
 content:"";
 content:none
}
a img{
 border:none
}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,menu,nav,section,summary{
 display:block
}
@font-face{
 font-family:quicksandbold;
 src:url(../fonts/quicksand-bold-webfont.eot);
 src:url(../fonts/quicksand-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(../fonts/quicksand-bold-webfont.woff) format("woff"),url(../fonts/quicksand-bold-webfont.ttf) format("truetype"),url(../fonts/quicksand-bold-webfont.svg#quicksandbold) format("svg");
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal
}
@font-face{
 font-family:quicksandregular;
 src:url(../fonts/quicksand-regular-webfont.eot);
 src:url(../fonts/quicksand-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(../fonts/quicksand-regular-webfont.woff) format("woff"),url(../fonts/quicksand-regular-webfont.ttf) format("truetype"),url(../fonts/quicksand-regular-webfont.svg#quicksandregular) format("svg");
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal
}
article li,h1,p,span{
 font-family:quicksandregular
}
#blogintro header,.fpblog time,footer p,a,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
 font-family:quicksandbold
}
#primaryNav,.lrg-font,h2{
 font-size:1.4em
}
h1{
 font-size:8vw
}
h1 span.full{
 font-size:11vw
}
.width-fix{
 width:89%
}
.rotate p{
 font-size:1em;
 line-height:1
}
p,.stop-rotate p,.stop-rotate ul li{
 line-height:1.4;
 font-size:1.2em
}
h3,h4{
 font-size:1.4em
}
small{
 font-size:0.8em
}
ul{
 text-align:left;
 margin:0 auto;
 max-width:800px;
 padding-left:30px;
 width:70%
}
ul li{
 padding-bottom:5px
}
ul li::before{
 content:"\2022";
 color:#000;
 display:inline-block;
 width:1em;
 margin-left:-1em
}
body{
 background-color:#27AAE1
}
*{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:0;
 margin:0
}
.hide{
 display:none
}
.full-height{
 display:grid;
 width:100vw;
 height:calc(100vh - 92px)
}
.limit-width p,footer{
 margin:0 auto;
 max-width:90%
}
.limit-width-lrg p{
 margin:0 auto;
 width:65%;
 max-width:870px
}
.white{
 color:#fff
}
.bg-blue{
 background-color:#27AAE1
}
.blue{
 color:#27AAE1
}
.bold,.bold li,.bold p{
 font-family:quicksandbold
}
.cntr{
 text-align:center
}
.bg-white{
 background-color:#fff
}
.rotate{
 transform:rotate(-15deg)
}
.stop-rotate{
 transform:rotate(15deg)
}
.txt-center{
 display:grid;
 align-items:center
}
.txt-base{
 display:grid;
 align-items:end
}
.force-base{
 bottom:0;
 position:absolute;
 left:calc(50% - 200px)
}
.mrg-top{
 margin-top:10%
}
body .mrg-top-sml{
 margin-top:40px
}
.pad-top{
 padding-top:20px
}
.pad-top-lrg{
 padding-top:40px
}
.pad-top-xlrg{
 padding-top:13.75vh
}
.pad-btm{
 padding-bottom:20px
}
.pad-top-sml{
 padding-top:5%
}
.section-pad{
 padding:15% 0
}
.bg-2 .button{
 color:#ECEFF1;
 border-color:#ECEFF1
}
.button--winona{
 overflow:hidden;
 padding:0;
 -webkit-transition:border-color 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
 transition:border-color 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
 transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1)
}
.button--winona::after,.button--winona>span{
 padding:1em 0;
 transition:transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
 transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
 -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1)
}
.button--winona:hover{
 background-color:#fff
}
.button--border-thick{
 border:3px solid
}
.button--text-thick{
 font-weight:600
}
.button--text-upper{
 letter-spacing:2px;
 text-transform:uppercase
}
.button--size-s{
 font-size:14px
}
.button{
 min-width:150px;
 max-width:210px;
 display:block;
 margin:0 auto;
 border:3px #27AAE1;
 border-style:dashed;
 background:rgba(39,170,225,0.12);
 color:inherit;
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
 -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale
}
button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{
 -webkit-appearance:button;
 cursor:pointer
}
button,input{
 line-height:normal
}
button{
 align-items:flex-start;
 text-align:center
}
.button--winona>span{
 display:block
}
.button>span{
 vertical-align:middle
}
.button--winona::after,.button--winona>span{
 padding:1em 0;
 -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
 transition:transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
 transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1)
}
.button--winona:hover::after{
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}
.button--winona::after{
 content:attr(data-text);
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 opacity:0;
 color:#000;
 -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 25%, 0);
 transform:translate3d(0, 25%, 0)
}
.button--winona:hover>span{
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
 transform:translate3d(0, -25%, 0)
}
a.btn-link{
 color:inherit;
 text-decoration:none
}
#primaryNav{
 padding:0 20px;
 position:relative;
 text-align:center
}
#primaryNav a:first-of-type{
 padding-top:20px
}
#primaryNav a{
 display:none;
 color:#fff;
 padding-bottom:20px;
 text-decoration:none
}
#primaryNav a#nav-burger{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 right:20px;
 top:-50px;
 z-index:999
}
#primaryNav.open a{
 display:block
}
#primaryNav #nav-burger{
 width:25px;
 height:23px;
 position:relative;
 -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
 transform:rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
 transition:.5s ease-in-out;
 cursor:pointer
}
#primaryNav #nav-burger span{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 height:3px;
 width:100%;
 background:#fff;
 border-radius:9px;
 opacity:1;
 left:0;
 -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
 transform:rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
 transition:.25s ease-in-out
}
#primaryNav #nav-burger span:nth-child(1){
 top:0px;
 -webkit-transform-origin:left center;
 -moz-transform-origin:left center;
 -o-transform-origin:left center;
 transform-origin:left center
}
#primaryNav #nav-burger span:nth-child(2){
 top:7px;
 -webkit-transform-origin:left center;
 -moz-transform-origin:left center;
 -o-transform-origin:left center;
 transform-origin:left center
}
#primaryNav #nav-burger span:nth-child(3){
 top:14px;
 -webkit-transform-origin:left center;
 -moz-transform-origin:left center;
 -o-transform-origin:left center;
 transform-origin:left center
}
#primaryNav.open #nav-burger span:nth-child(1){
 -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
 transform:rotate(45deg);
 top:0;
 left:5px
}
#primaryNav.open #nav-burger span:nth-child(2){
 width:0%;
 opacity:0
}
#primaryNav.open #nav-burger span:nth-child(3){
 -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
 top:18px;
 left:5px
}

#logo{
 padding-top:20px;
 text-align:center
}
#logo svg{
 max-width:120px
}
.spill{
 width:130%;
 margin-left:-15%
}
.stripe-sml{
 height:11vh
}
.stripe-sml p{
 line-height:1.5;
 padding-bottom:18px
}
.stripe-lrg{
 height:18vh
}
#scroll-down{
 max-width:30px
}
footer{
 text-align:center
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 50px){
 .foo2{
  display:none
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 501px){
 h1{
  font-size:40px
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 801px){
 .limit-width p{
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:60%
}
 .full-height{
  height:calc(100vh - 154px)
}
 .mrg-top{
  margin-top:5%
}
 h1{
  font-size:6vw;
  line-height:1.4
}
 h1 .white.bold{
  line-height:2;
  font-size:0.73em
}
 h1 .full{
  margin-bottom:-2%
}
 h3,h4{
  font-size:2vw
}
 ul{
  width:100%;
  padding-left:80px
}
 .lrg-title{
  font-size:3vw
}
 #primaryNav a{
  display:inline-block !important;
  padding:20px 10px
}
 #primaryNav a#nav-burger{
  display:none !important
}
 .height-override{
  height:auto
}
 .stripe-lrg h1 br{
  display:none
}
 #scroll-down{
  bottom:20px;
  position:absolute;
  left:calc(50% - 30px)
}
}
html,body{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Lorem ipsum. | Lorem ipsum.Lorem ipsum.</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="#" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link href="/v2/assets/styles/screen.css?236" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
  <header class="bg-blue" id="top">
  <div id="logo" class="float">
    <a href="#">
  <svg id="a3ce43e8-fb65-4daf-adde-8a5b63a92355" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 115.71 66.3"><defs><style>.b619fcf4-8929-47b2-8667-741fdd67a7c1{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>Lorem ipsum.</title><g id="b100e093-4f59-489c-bf94-25ea2e312f6f" data-name="Group 1"><path id="ba36fb6c-3443-4def-ab41-3ef77b8ca3b4" data-name="Path 1" class="b619fcf4-8929-47b2-8667-741fdd67a7c1" d="M90.17,52.58a22,22,0,1,1,19.07-33.09l6.36-3.65a29.57,29.57,0,1,0-.09,29.52l-6.33-3.68A22,22,0,0,1,90.17,52.58Z" transform="translate(0.11 -0.31)"/><path id="e0462462-ad6f-44e0-9063-0ba927c00cc9" data-name="Path 2" class="b619fcf4-8929-47b2-8667-741fdd67a7c1" d="M45.7,5.27a29.5,29.5,0,0,0-16.41-5h0A29.63,29.63,0,0,0,4.53,13.57C.28,20-.24,24.86-.09,34.43V66.61H7.18V49.87A29.7,29.7,0,1,0,45.7,5.27Zm1.93,37c-.25.36-.5.72-.76,1.06l-.24.32c-.19.24-.38.47-.58.7l-.28.33c-.21.23-.41.45-.63.67a3.07,3.07,0,0,1-.25.26c-.3.3-.6.59-.91.87l-.09.08c-.28.25-.57.5-.87.73l-.3.24L42,48l-.34.23c-.25.18-.51.34-.77.5a2.61,2.61,0,0,1-.28.17c-.35.22-.71.42-1.07.61l-.16.08-1,.46-.35.15c-.26.12-.53.23-.8.33l-.37.14c-.3.11-.59.21-.89.3a2.29,2.29,0,0,1-.28.09c-.38.12-.78.23-1.17.33l-.25.06-.95.2-.39.07-.84.12-.4,0q-.48.06-1,.09l-.26,0c-.4,0-.81,0-1.22,0h-.23c-.4,0-.8,0-1.21,0l-.34,0-1.39-.15-.19,0c-.4-.06-.81-.14-1.22-.22l-.35-.08c-.46-.1-.91-.22-1.37-.35l-.14,0c-.41-.12-.82-.26-1.23-.41l-.34-.13c-.45-.18-.9-.36-1.34-.57l-.08,0c-.41-.19-.82-.41-1.23-.63l-.33-.19c-.43-.24-.85-.5-1.27-.78A22,22,0,0,1,10.9,17.79c.24-.36.5-.72.75-1.06l.25-.32c.18-.24.37-.47.57-.7l.29-.33c.2-.23.41-.45.62-.67l.25-.27c.3-.3.6-.59.91-.86l.12-.1c.27-.24.55-.48.84-.71l.32-.25.7-.51.35-.24c.25-.17.5-.34.76-.5l.28-.17c.35-.21.71-.41,1.07-.6l.19-.1c.3-.16.6-.3.92-.44l.36-.17.79-.32.38-.15L22.5,9l.28-.09c.39-.12.78-.22,1.17-.32l.27-.06c.31-.08.62-.14.92-.2l.4-.07.83-.13.41-.05,1-.09L28,8c.4,0,.81,0,1.21,0h.26c.39,0,.79,0,1.18,0L31,8l1.38.15.21,0q.6.09,1.2.21l.35.08c.46.1.91.22,1.36.35l.16.05c.41.12.81.26,1.22.41l.34.13c.45.17.89.36,1.33.56l.08,0c.42.2.82.41,1.23.63l.33.19c.43.24.85.5,1.27.77a22.07,22.07,0,0,1,6.18,30.58Z" transform="translate(0.11 -0.31)"/></g></svg>
 </a>
  </div>
</header>

<nav id="primaryNav" class="bg-blue header-nav">
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">About Us</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="nav-burger" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <span></span>
 <span></span>
 <span></span>
  </a>
</nav>  
  <!-- Home Content -->
<article>
  <section class="bg-blue full-height">
   <section class="rotate bg-white txt-base cntr mrg-top stripe-sml spill">
  <p class="force-base"><span class="bold">We're rebuilding our website...</span><br>Check back shortly to see what we've been up to!</p>
 </section>
   <section class="cntr spill txt-center rotate stripe-lrg height-override">
  <h1>
   <div class="full">Lorem ipsum.</div>
   <br>
   <div class="white bold">Lorem ipsum. Digital Agency</div>
  </h1>
 </section>
   <section class="rotate cntr bg-white txt-center stripe-lrg spill">
  <p>Think web design, think Lorem ipsum.</p>
    <a class="btn-link" href="#about-us">
    <button class="button button--winona button--border-thick button--round-l button--text-upper button--size-s button--text-thick" data-text="Read More"><span>About Us</span></button>
  </a>
    <p>We Rethink, We Build, We Optimise</p>
 </section>
 <section class="cntr stripe-lrg">
     <a href="#about-us"><svg id="scroll-down" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 27.22 26.16"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>Scroll Down</title><g id="Group_2" data-name="Group 2"><path id="Path_3" data-name="Path 3" class="cls-1" d="M12.81,26.14,1.11,14.44a1.91,1.91,0,0,1,2.7-2.7h0L14.16,22.1,24.51,11.75a1.91,1.91,0,0,1,2.7,2.7h0l-11.7,11.7a1.91,1.91,0,0,1-2.69,0Z" transform="translate(-0.55 -0.55)"/></g><g id="Group_4" data-name="Group 4"><path id="Path_3-2" data-name="Path 3-2" class="cls-1" d="M12.81,15.5,1.11,3.8a1.91,1.91,0,0,1,2.7-2.7h0L14.16,11.46,24.51,1.11a1.91,1.91,0,0,1,2.7,2.7h0l-11.7,11.7a1.91,1.91,0,0,1-2.69,0Z" transform="translate(-0.55 -0.55)"/></g></svg></a>
 </section>
  </section>
  <section class="section-pad limit-width">
 <h2 id="about-us" class="white cntr lrg-title pad-btm">About Us</h2>
 <p class="bold white cntr">Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.</p>
  </section>
  <section class="rotate bold bg-white section-pad cntr txt-center pad-btm limit-width-lrg spill">
 <span class="stop-rotate">
    <h3 class="pad-btm">Work With Us</h3>
 <p class="bold pad-btm">Lorem ipsum.</p>
 <p class="pad-btm">Lorem ipsum.</p> 
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <h4 class="pad-btm pad-top-lrg mrg-top-sml">What we're looking for:</h4>
 <ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
 </ul>
 <a class="btn-link" href="#">
   <button class="mrg-top-sml button button--winona button--border-thick button--round-l button--text-upper button--size-s button--text-thick" data-text="Apply Now"><span>Apply Now</span></button>
 </a>
 </span>
  </section>
</article>
  <footer class="pad-top-xlrg">
  <p class="pad-top white"><small>Lorem Ipsum is a trading style of 'Lorem Ipsum'.</small></p>
  <p class="white pad-btm"><small>&copy; Lorem Ipsum Copyright 2020, All Rights Reserved.</small></p>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Dan382 Glad that helps! Cheers